Why are props in my generic component accepted by TypeScript only if I specify their type explicitly as "object"?
I've been trying to implement a component in React which can be either a link or a button. If the value of "as" prop equalts to "button" then it is a button and hence accepts all button-related props and vice versa. Everything works perfectly, however, there is one thing I completely don't understand. The props that I spread ({...props}) are not accepted by typescript unless I explicitly tell TypeScript that its type is object. Why is it happening?
THIS IS FINE
import { ComponentProps } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

type TextComponentType = "link" | "button";

type TextComponentProps<T extends TextComponentType> = {
  as: T;
} & ComponentProps<T extends "link" ? "a" : "button">;

export const TextComponent = <T extends TextComponentType>(
  props: TextComponentProps<T>
) => {
  return <StyledButton {...(props as object)}>HEhe</StyledButton>;
};

const StyledButton = styled.button`
  color: red;
`;


I tried to understand the warning it gives me, however, it's a wall of text that seems to difficult to descipher.
THIS IS NOT FINE
import { ComponentProps } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

type TextComponentType = "link" | "button";

type TextComponentProps<T extends TextComponentType> = {
  as: T;
} & ComponentProps<T extends "link" ? "a" : "button">;

export const TextComponent = <T extends TextComponentType>(
  props: TextComponentProps<T>
) => {
  return <StyledButton {...props}>HEhe</StyledButton>;
};

const StyledButton = styled.button`
  color: red;
`;



Seems like the problem is with the prop "as". I get the following warning, trying to pass only "as" prop: Property 'as' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & FastOmit<DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes, HTMLButtonElement>, never>'. It works if I write instead (in the component body): const as = props.as as TextComponentType. Either it doesn't work as it's supposed to, or I'm a total noob in TypeScript (which I guess is the latter).

Oof, I don't know what's going on with react/styled-components and their complicated type definitions either. If you don't get enough engagement here I'd suggest trying to provide a [mre] without dependence on these libraries, by inlining enough type declarations to reproduce the error. Right now I'd need to hunt down type declarations in libraries and it's not something I'm inclined to do.
